# Can dogs really die if they eat too much chocolate?

Tags: dogs

Can dogs really die if they eat too much chocolate? Is there a scientific reason why puppies do that head tilt thing?

Comment: No chocolate at all should be given at dogs. Sugar is harmful to them.